# Converting word newsletter to html

Tags: c#, html, .net-4.0, ms-word

I tried converting word newsletter to html by File->Save as->Other formats and then choose .html, but they aren't at all the same.
For example, in the .docx file a has an image on the margin and it isn't shown in html.

Is there an API or some idea that would help me with the conversion?

Comment: The only advice I could give is to post conversion manually add back the images. I have never tried such a conversion myself, but since image files are external to html files (not embedded like they can be in a word document), then the converter has no external image file to link an image to. You would need to create your image in `.jpg` or `.png` etc. and then manually add it as either a background image or via the `img` tag to your converted html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML was orginally not designed to be a layout preserving format. If you want to offer a newsletter which was created using Word on a web page, best option may be to create a PDF from that and allow your audience to download it. You can, however, try to convert that PDF afterwards to HTML with a tool  like this one

http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-to-html-converter.html

There are also some commercial solutions for converting Word to HTML directly, just google "convert word to html".